# React context value sets to default on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-context, next.js13

I'm using NextJs 13 for my project and implementing context API in it. I have created **Context Privder** and wraps all child components inside it.

***contxetProvider.ts***

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

interface IChildrenProp {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

interface IAppContext {
  userId: number;
  setUserId: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
  userName: string;
  setUserName: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  userEmail: string;
  setUserEmail: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  userRole: string;
  setUserRole: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
}

export const AppContext = createContext<IAppContext>({
  userId: 0,
  setUserId: (): number => 0,
  userName: "",
  setUserName: () => "",
  userEmail: "",
  setUserEmail: () => "",
  userRole: "",
  setUserRole: () => "",
});

export const ContextProvider: React.FC<IChildrenProp> = ({ children }) => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = React.useState<number>(0);
  const [userName, setUserName] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = React.useState<string>("");

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        userId,
        setUserId,
        userName,
        setUserName,
        userEmail,
        setUserEmail,
        userRole,
        setUserRole,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

***layout.tsx***

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: IChildrenProp) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={`${inter.className} bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-700 h-screen dark:text-slate-300 text-slate-700`}
      >
        <ContextProvider>{children}</ContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Inside children component, I'm fetching the API and setting the value in context.

***children component***

```
"use client"

const {userId, setUserId, userName, setUserName} = React.useContext(AppContext)

console.log(userId, userName)

let result = await fetchApi()
if (result) {
  setUserId(result.id)
  setUserName(result.username)
}
```

After fetching the API and setting the data of context, console.log gives me the correct context data but when I refresh the page, console.log gives the default value of context. The context data gets lost on page refresh. So, I'm not getting what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: If you want to store data between page refreshes, you should consider loading data from `window.localStorage` or have you app defer its behaviour until the initial values are loaded from the endpoint.

Comment: I refresh the page after setting the value in context. After setting the data, when the page re-render, the console.log gives the correct data from the context. After that, when I refresh the page, it gives me the default value of context.